# The correct usage of "come along"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

> 1. Would happiness come along Pain? (meaning come together)
> 2. Would happiness and pain come along (meaning come together)

Is 2 a correct usage of come along, when I mean the two things in question come together? In other words, the question is whether "A and B come along" can be used instead of "A and B come together"?

Comment: Just as in your [previous question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/182959/the-meaning-of-would-in-the-mentioned-context), please clarify what ‘A’ and ‘B’ refer to. If these refer to people, consider using names (like Alfred and Brandon) instead of letters in future questions. Longer sentences would help, too, so that we better understand what you are trying to convey.

Comment: "You stay here near the entrance, and when Ted and Bob come along, let them know that we're sitting up in section 26."

Comment: **come along** = "arrive" in my example above. As a command, *Come along now* it means "Accompany me as we go to some destination" or "Do as I have asked" or in a question "Do you want to come along?" it means "Would you like to accompany me|us?"

Comment: The "example context" seems a bit esoteric to me. I can just about imagine a native speaker asking *Will happiness **bring** pain?*, but that's a fairly weird juxtaposition in the first place. Can't we have an example that actually makes sense as something a normal person might reasonably ask?

Comment: I think there is confusion between **come along as accompany** versus **come along (with) as in to occur**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would happiness come along Pain? (meaning come together)
>
> Would happiness and pain come along (meaning come together)

These sentences don't make sense with the meaning you have intended. "Come along" usually means "travel as well", as in "I will come along with you to the store." Note that "along" is an adverb in this case and not a preposition, which is why we need the preposition "with". You could rewrite the first sentence as:

> Would happiness come along with pain?

meaning that happiness accompanies pain. It is worth noting that when A comes along with B, A is implied to be secondary to B, such that B will probably be going somewhere whether or not A joins. Accordingly, your second sentence seems to imply that both happiness and pain are joining some third thing, for example excitement. You could say:

> Excitement was coming. Would happiness and pain come along too?

I added "too" to the above example because it emphasizes that happiness and pain are joining excitement. It sounds more natural but is not strictly necessary. If your second sentence simply means that both happiness and pain will be accompanying each other, you should not use "along". A better sentence would be:

> Would happiness and pain come together?